# Parsing CSV String Using supercsv

Tags: csv, supercsv

I have been having a hard time parsing this csv string using supercsv.

"      00751016"    "AUTH             " "              19.81"   "            "  "           "   "WA CONSTRUCTION LTD              " "GHS"   "              19.81"   "              19.81"

Basically Fields are enclosed in "" and separated by spaces no headers.
Any help will is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the separator is `tab` instead of space(s).

Comment: Thanks it works now. Thanks for the tip. What text editor do you use ?

Comment: I just put this post in edit mode to check. If you then move the cursor, it jumps over the tabs.